# Recieving sensor output continiously

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to control an arduino micro controller from android phone.
I need help to to continuously receive the output from the temperature sensor and display it on text view.

Here is the code:

```
package com.war10ck6001gmail.finalproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public ToggleButton fan, light, manauto;
    public Button inc, dec;
    public TextView temp;
    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    TCPClient mTcpClient = null;
    public connectTask conctTask = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // connect to the server

        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temprature);
        fan = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.fanbutton);
        light = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.lightbutton);
        manauto = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.manauto);
        inc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        dec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrement);

        Automatic(light);
        Automatic(fan);
        Automatic(inc);
        Automatic(dec);
        conctTask = new connectTask();

        conctTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        mTcpClient = null;

        manauto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Manual(light);
                    Manual(fan);
                    Manual(inc);
                    Manual(dec);
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("Man");
                }
                else {
                    Automatic(light);
                    Automatic(fan);
                    Automatic(inc);
                    Automatic(dec);
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("Auto");
                }
            }
        });
        light.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("0");
                }
                else {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("1");
                }
            }
        });
        fan.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("2");
                }
                else {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("3");
                }
            }
        });
        inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage("4");

            }
        });
        dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage("5");
            }
        });
    }

    public void Automatic(Button btn) {
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    public void Manual(Button btn) {
        btn.setEnabled(true);
        btn.getBackground().setColorFilter(null);
    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPClient> {
        String finalmessage;

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(final String... message) {
            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {

                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(final String message) {

                    try {
                        //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                        //publishProgress(message);

                        if (message != null) {
                            //finalmessage = message;
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    temp.setText(message);
                                }
                            });
                            System.out.println("Return Message from Socket::::: >>>>> " + message);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();
            if (mTcpClient != null) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage("Initial Message when connected with Socket Server");
            }

               /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        temp.setText(finalmessage);
                    }
                });*/
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_master) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_bedroom) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Bedroom.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_Cbedroom) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cbedroom.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_diningroom) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Diningroom.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here is the class which has the onmessage recieved

```
public class TCPClient {

    public String serverMessage;
    /**
     * Specify the Server Ip Address here. Whereas our Socket Server is started.
     */
    public static final String SERVERIP = "10.5.38.148"; // your computer IP address
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8888;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    MainActivity mainActivity = null;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(final OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            System.out.println("message: " + message);
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }


    public void stopClient() {
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        mRun = true;
        while (mRun) {
            try {
                //here you must put your computer's IP address.
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

                Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Connecting...");

                //create a socket to make the connection with the server
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                try {
                    //send the message to the server
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                    Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Sent.");
                    Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Done.");

                    //receive the message which the server sends back
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                    //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server

                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);

                        Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                    }
                    serverMessage = null;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                    // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);
            }
        }
    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'I need help to to continuously receive ..'. Indeed. But you did not tell why. You did not tell the problem you have now. You did not tell for instance that the asynctask has long finished when messageReceived is called. We do not know about that class member messageReceived as you did not tell. Also we cannot see how sendMessage() should work. Is this by wifi or bluetooth?

Comment: hi man thanks for the response i wanted to receive data continuously from sensor... please tell me how i can accomplish that using sockets... thanks in advance.

Comment: `i wanted to receive data continuously from sensor.`. You already told that before. Please don't only repeat yourself. . You did not react on my comments. Why not? `thanks in advance`. ????

Comment: the problem i have now is it's not receiving the data sent from the arduino when the app starts... but after i sent a data it Starts receiving. do u think the asynctask will update the textview every time??

Comment: Where is an asynctask that updates a textview?

Comment: inside doinbackground...which says  temp.setText(message)

Comment: Well that code might be textually within doInBackground but it will be only exectuted long after doInBackgroud/your asynctask has finished. It is used in the messageReceived handler of the mTcpClient. But again: we cannot see where and when you call it.